# Three buttons show the same content. HOW?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three buttons(when clicked, the modal shows) with different content inside them (every button has its own content and it's different from the other buttons) and now no matter on which button I click, it shows the same content from the last button I've added. Can anyone explain me how to fix this?

I need this to be done by Monday so quick help would be much appreciated.

```
<div class="popup1">
    <style>

    /* The Modal (background) */
    .modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    }

    /* Modal Content */
    .modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 30%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
    }

    /* Add Animation */
    @-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
    }

    @keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
    }

    /* The Close Button */
    .close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    }

    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    .modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5ca6b8;
    color: white;
    }

    .modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

    .modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
    }
    </style>

    <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
    <button id="myBtn">Sponsors</button>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <h2>Our Sponsors</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <ul>
            <li>MONG</li>
            <li>SCNG</li>
            <li>Feel Slovenia</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
    btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    }
    </script>
</div>

<div class="popup2">
        <style>

        /* The Modal (background) */
        .modal2 {
        display: none; /* Hidden by default */
        position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
        z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
        padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%; /* Full width */
        height: 100%; /* Full height */
        overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
        }

        /* Modal Content */
        .modal-content2 {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #fefefe;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 0;
        border: 1px solid #888;
        width: 30%;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
        -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
        animation-name: animatetop;
        animation-duration: 0.4s
        }

        /* Add Animation */
        @-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
        from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
        to {top:0; opacity:1}
        }

        @keyframes animatetop {
        from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
        to {top:0; opacity:1}
        }

        /* The Close Button */
        .close2 {
        color: white;
        float: right;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: bold;
        }

        .close2:hover,
        .close2:focus {
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        }

        .modal-header2 {
        padding: 2px 16px;
        background-color: #5ca6b8;
        color: white;
        }

        .modal-body2 {padding: 2px 16px;}

        .modal-footer2 {
        padding: 2px 16px;
        background-color: #5cb85c;
        color: white;
        }
        </style>

        <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
        <button id="myBtn2">My Gear</button>

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal2" class="modal2">

        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content2">
            <div class="modal-header2">
            <span class="close2">&times;</span>
            <h2>My gear</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body2">
            <ul>
                <li>Nikon D3100</li>
                <li>Sigma 10-20mm f/4</li>
                <li>Nikkor 70-300mm f4-5.6</li>
                <li>Nikkor 18-55mm f/3.5</li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>

        <script>
        // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById("myModal2");

        // Get the button that opens the modal
        var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn2");

        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close2")[0];

        // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
        btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
        }

        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        }

        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
        }
        </script>
</div>

<div class="popup3">
        <style>

        /* The Modal (background) */
        .modal3 {
        display: none; /* Hidden by default */
        position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
        z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
        padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%; /* Full width */
        height: 100%; /* Full height */
        overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
        }

        /* Modal Content */
        .modal-content3 {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #fefefe;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 0;
        border: 1px solid #888;
        width: 30%;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
        -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
        animation-name: animatetop;
        animation-duration: 0.4s
        }

        /* Add Animation */
        @-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
        from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
        to {top:0; opacity:1}
        }

        @keyframes animatetop {
        from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
        to {top:0; opacity:1}
        }

        /* The Close Button */
        .close3 {
        color: white;
        float: right;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: bold;
        }

        .close3:hover,
        .close3:focus {
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        }

        .modal-header3 {
        padding: 2px 16px;
        background-color: #5ca6b8;
        color: white;
        }

        .modal-body3 {padding: 2px 16px;}

        .modal-footer3 {
        padding: 2px 16px;
        background-color: #5cb85c;
        color: white;
        }
        </style>

        <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
        <button id="myBtn3">My Hobbies</button>

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal3" class="modal3">

        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content3">
            <div class="modal-header3">
            <span class="close3">&times;</span>
            <h2>My hobbies</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body3">
            <ul>
                <li>Photography</li>
                <li>Videography</li>
                <li>Traveling</li>
                <li>Racing</li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>

        <script>
        // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById("myModal3");

        // Get the button that opens the modal
        var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn3");

        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close3")[0];

        // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
        btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
        }

        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        }

        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
        }
        </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Please included your code with your question (don't ignore the statement about including code with a jsfiddle link).

Comment: I've added the code to my question now.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same variable `modal` for all three. So this:

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
```

gets overwritten by this

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal2");
```

which gets overwritten by this

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal3");
```

By the time the click callback happens, `modal` is only referring to the 3rd one, so that's the one you end up showing.

The fact that these are in different script tags does not isolate them. You're declaring these variables at the top level of their scripts (as opposed to in a function for example), and so they are global variables.